# wso2 carbon: how to hack the source and deploy the changes to a carbon server

Tags: wso2

I have the carbon source tree set up in eclipse - and have made some code changes.

Can I build just one component (e.g. org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui-4.1.0.jar) using maven / eclipse, and then deploy that to an existing carbon server?

I have tried dropping the built jar in the repository\deployment directory and restarting the server, but the changes don't appear to have been picked up.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the jars at `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/plugins`. Also delete the relevant existing jars from `repository/components/plugins`

Comment: I have put my version of `org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui-4.1.0.jar` in the `dropins` folder and restarted carbon.  However, my changes have not been deployed.

Comment: I have deleted the jar from `plugins`, and the feature management link has disappeared from the UI.  It seems that carbon couldn't find my jar in `dropins`.  I also tried copying my jar to the `plugins` folder, but that still no feature menu.

Comment: maven built the jar as `org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui-4.1.0.jar` instead of `org.wso2.carbon.feature.mgt.ui_4.1.0.jar`.  I renamed the hyphen to and underscore in the plugins folder, restarted it and now my changes are showing.  Many thanks!!!